# How to stop the cycle by pressing a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, vlc

I have an application on tkinter to switch over ip cameras via rtsp:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black")
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn_file = tk.Button(text="Home", command=self.Btn)
        self.btn_file.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
    
    def Btn(self):
        self.btn_file.destroy()
        cmr1 = tk.Button(text="cam1-1", command=lambda: self.cmr("rtsp://LOG:PASS@IP/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&unicast=true&proto=Onvif"))
        cmr1.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

    def cmr(self, path):
        a = Camera_Open(path)
```

I saved the code for an example

The class that the cmr function calls looks like this

```
class Camera_Open(object,):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.connect(path, 0)
  
    def connect(self, path, a):        
        player = vlc.Instance()
        # creating a new media
        media = player.media_new(path)
        # creating a media player object
        media_player = player.media_player_new()
        media_player.set_media(media)
        # setting video scale
        media_player.video_set_scale(0)
        # start playing video
        media_player.play()
        value = media_player.event_manager()
        value = str(value)
        while a == 0:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
                print('asdasd')
                break
            pass
```

This is just a call to an object by reference which, when esc is pressed, turns off if you call this class outside of tkinter, but if in tkinter, the window with the camera output will not close

How to fix it ?

Comment: `while a == 0:`, where is `a` defined? Outside `tkinter` bindings can be handled by `keyboard` or something similar and inside `tkinter` you can use `bind` method

Comment: In general, there is a While True loop: I accidentally left this when I was experimenting.

Comment: So the problem is the code works fine outside tkinter window but when inside, it fails?

Comment: It looks like it's going out of order.  But in general, it registers a keystroke, I checked through print('ss'), but it does not close the window itself

Comment: Could you please use an example to show what you meant by stopping the loop of another function using bind

Comment: I was just confirm basic details that will help the future people viewing the question. I don't know the answer or the reason

Comment: As long as that `while a == 0` loop is running, tkinter is going to be unable to do anything, including being unable to refresh the window.

Comment: If I remove While a == 0, the class is still called in some kind of thread of the tkinter

Comment: That is, I can open several cameras in a row in several windows